# LWC: Issue with loading static resources

Tags: lightning-web-components, static-resources, promises

I've incorporated the code documented in the following article into a new component:

[Play YouTube Videos Through Lightning Web Components](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2019/07/play-youtube-videos-through-lightning-web-components.html)

It seems like the two JS files referenced, **iframe_api.js** and **widgetapi.js**, don't always load when the component is first loaded.  In other words, initially the embedded YouTube player craps out the very first time I load the component.  Afterwards, the resources load fine.  This is true even when I clear my Chrome cache--which seems odd to me since this would force my browser client to refetch the static resource from the org.

I thought that the use of the `Promise.all()` to encapsulate the two `loadScript()` calls would ensure that both JS resources are loaded before continuing, but in my experience, that is not the case.

```
renderedCallback() {
        .
        .
        .
        if (window.YT) {
            if (this.player) {
                this.player.cueVideoById(this.youTubeId);
            } else {
                this.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady();
            }
        } else {
            Promise.all([
                loadScript(this, YouTubePath + '/iframe_api.js'),
                loadScript(this, YouTubePath + '/widgetapi.js')
            ])
                .then(() => {
                    this.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady();
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log('Error with loading the YouTube static resources');
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
                    this.showErrorToast(error);
                });
        }
    }
```

I've tried splitting the two JS files into their own individual static resources, but the same problem happens.

Is there another way I can address this issue?

Comment: what does "craps out" mean?

Comment: @AndyRay "craps out" = "does not load".  Let me see if I can get the exact error message.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure why that method shouldn't work, but in your specific case, this [playground](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/DovdJ8Tuf/19/edit) should provide you with what you need. It's a component that plays YouTube videos given an ID.

Here's the relevant code:

```
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';
import { loadScript } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import { YT as YoutubePath1 } from './YouTubeJS/iframe_api.js';
import { YT as YouTubePath2 } from './YouTubeJS/widget_api.js';

export default class BasicYouTubePlayer extends LightningElement {
    @api youTubeId;
    player;

    renderedCallback() {
        if (!this.youTubeId) {
            return;
        }

        if (window.YT) {
            if (this.player) {
                this.player.cueVideoById(this.youTubeId);
            } else {
                this.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady();
            }
        } else {
            Promise.all([
                loadScript(this, YouTubePath1),
                loadScript(this, YouTubePath2)
            ])
                .then(() => {
                    this.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady();
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    this.showErrorToast(error);
                });
        }
    }

    onPlayerError(e) {
        let explanation = '';
        if (e.data === 2) {
            explanation = 'Invalid YouTube ID';
        } else if (e.data === 5) {
            explanation =
                'The requested content cannot be played in an HTML5 player or another error related to the HTML5 player has occurred.';
        } else if (e.data === 100) {
            explanation =
                'The video requested was not found. This error occurs when a video has been removed (for any reason) or has been marked as private.';
        } else if (e.data === 101 || e.data === 150) {
            explanation =
                'The owner of the requested video does not allow it to be played in embedded players.';
        }

        this.showErrorToast(explanation);
    }

    showErrorToast(explanation) {
        const evt = new ShowToastEvent({
            title: 'Error loading YouTube player',
            message: explanation,
            variant: 'error'
        });
        this.dispatchEvent(evt);
    }

    onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        const containerElem = this.template.querySelector('.wrapper');
        const playerElem = document.createElement('DIV');
        playerElem.className = 'player';
        containerElem.appendChild(playerElem);

        this.player = new window.YT.Player(playerElem, {
            height: '390',
            width: '100%',
            videoId: this.youTubeId,
            events: {
                onError: this.onPlayerError.bind(this)
            }
        });
    }
}
```

---

```
<template>
    <template if:true={youTubeId}>
        <div class="wrapper" lwc:dom="manual"></div>
    </template>
    <template if:false={youTubeId}>
        <lightning-card  title="Empty YouTube ID found. Please specify a YouTube ID."></lightning-card>
    </template>
</template>
```

---

Note: the two imported files need to be modified to support importing. Add the following lines to the end of each file, as noted [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/310787/2984):

```
const YT1 = window.YT;
export { YT1 as YT };
```

Comment: That's the same playground you helped me with on this question:  https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/310786/lightning-web-components-playground-issue-with-imported-js-files

Comment: I thought that what we did for the YouTube resources in the playground (putting them in a folder in the component and referencing them that way) was something that only applied to the playground.  This technique is more fool proof than loading via static resources?

Comment: @MichaelSobczak Either way should work reliably. I found that some modifications are apparently necessary for the method in this answer, but in *general*, you can indeed load scripts via import from the same or other components. However, loadScript should *also* work, I was just trying to provide an alternative. I'm going to try to get this working and I'll update the answer when I can.

Comment: I took the code from the playground and created a new component with it, copy/pasting the contents of each file exactly.  I then added the component to a Lighting home page.  I get the following error:  Cannot read property 'parentNode' of undefined.  Very strange.

Comment: @MichaelSobczak Ditto. I think it's a locker service issue. I'm trying to come up with an alternative.

Comment: any luck with this issue?  No rush, just curious.