# LWC Loading multiple scripts at once

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

I want to make sure all the scripts are loaded, before I do any operation,

```
    renderedCallback() {
    Promise.all([
        loadScript(this, JSPDF),
        loadScript(this,DOMPURIFY)
    ]).then(() => {
        window.console.log('Files loaded.New');
        console.log('MVK inside connected callback-->'+this.articleIds);
        this.handleSearch();
    }).catch(error => {
        window.console.log("Error " + error.body.message);
    });
}
```

THis works, however as it is asynchronous, callbacks are getting out of order. So I'm concerned if that'll be a problem

I want something like this in LWC:

```
<ltng:require scripts="{!join(',', $Resource.Jquery, $Resource.bootstrap + '/BootstrapJs.min.js'}" styles="{!$Resource.bootstrap + '/BootstrapCss.min.css'}" afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.doInit}" />
```

Here we are joining scripts.

Comment: were you able to load and use DOMPURIFY in lwc? If so, could you share the static resource files besides the code?

Comment: Were you able to use DOMPurify on lwc after loading the library? If so, could you share a bit more detail of the code and static resource file you used? I'm having this problem https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/378603/third-party-library-dompurify-on-lwc-failed-to-execute-createnodeiterator-on?noredirect=1#comment548678_378603

Answer (score 3):

`Promise.all` waits for all the promises to `resolve()` (assuming none `reject()`, which would go to the `.catch()`, so `then()` won't be called until all the `loadScript()` functions to finish. In other words, it shouldn't matter the order in which the scripts load. Note that the Aura version also loads the scripts in any order; the `join()` method is needed only because of how `ltng:require` parses the `scripts` attribute. There is no guarantee that the order will be maintained.

Note that if you absolutely wanted to force the scripts to load before even `connectedCallback()`, you could attempt to expose the scripts by way of `import`ing. There's an example of this in this [answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/310787/2984). If your code minified is less than 131kb (per script), this can save you the trouble of loading scripts asynchronously.