# Third Party Library DOMPurify on lwc - Failed to execute 'createNodeIterator' on 'Document'

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, lightning-experience, static-resources, third-party

I'm trying to load [DOMPurify](https://github.com/cure53/DOMPurify/tree/abf62956a8ac86c74b1954274dd6b5b9813094ba) in lwc in order to sanitize some data, but I cannot find a way to make the library work.

I've tried with the minified js file as static resource, with the full files, and also adding the minified file as an lwc and importing it in my component directly. None of them seems to work.

Here's a sample of the static resource attempt with the [min js file](https://github.com/cure53/DOMPurify/blob/main/dist/purify.min.js), that follows the logic in this doc https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.js_third_party_library .

What could be happening?

```
.
.
import { loadScript } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
import DOMPURIFY from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/DOMPurify';

export default class myclass extends LightningElement {

    DOMPurifyInitialized = false
    
    renderedCallback() {
        if (this.DOMPurifyInitialized) {
            return;
        }
        this.DOMPurifyInitialized = true;
        
        Promise.all([
            loadScript(this, DOMPURIFY)
        ])
            .then(() => {
                console.log('inside promise')
                this.initDOMPurify()
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                this.dispatchEvent(
                    new ShowToastEvent({
                        title: 'Error loading DOMPurify',
                        message: error.message,
                        variant: 'error'
                    })
                );
            });
    }

    initDOMPurify() {
        console.log(DOMPurify.sanitize(`<img src=x onerror=alert(1)//>`))
    }
.
.
}
```

[image]

Comment: Have you check if the HTML file doesn't have any syntax errors? Also, have you checked if DOMPurify has any dependencies which also needs to be loaded as static resource? Any error that state '... might just need to refresh it...' could be due to any these issues.

Comment: Since I was testing functionality the html file does have anything that could interfere, i'm just trying to log a sanitized string. As for the files, in the example I'm using just the minified js file, no others. I've also tried loading the whole non-minified files with no luck.

Comment: Looks like you have posted an updated error message, so I'm assuming that the static resource is getting loaded successfully. Were you able to debug and locate which exact line is throwing this error? May be `DOMPurify` isn't Lightning Locker compliant? It could be violating any one of the points mentioned [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.js_third_party_guidance).

Comment: Yes now It's loading, but it throws that error as soon as I try to use it. Maybe is related to the fact that it tries to use 'document' object and this might cause issues with locker compliance that you mention.

Comment: JFYI: While this JS library might be non-compliant with Lightning Locker, the presence of `document`, `window` etc. within the library may not be the reason for this non-compliance (but the way they are used could be a reason). Most 3rd party libraries use these, but lightning framework intercepts them via `secureDocument`,`secureWindow` etc. and provides support for some APIs as mentioned [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/locker-service-viewer).

Comment: At least nodeIterator and Node appear as supported in the documentation.

Comment: Yes, but the error suggests that the element on which this method is being called may not be of type Node.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137175/discussion-between-teo-and-arut).

Comment: how did this go? were you able to solve this?