# JSZip in LWC (Salesforce): JSZip is imported but the system does throws an error

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have the LWC and I need download the folder with files in zip format.
I found JSZip library.Downloaded this file (js). Added its to static resources and import its on my LWC and loaded this file used loadScript:

```
import JSZip from "@salesforce/resourceUrl/jszip"
...

async connectedCallback(){
        await loadScript(this, JSZip)
        .then(()=>{
            console.log('success load');
        })
```

But when i create a zip the system throws an error:

```
 async downloadFolder(event){
        const folder = event.detail;
        const zip = new JSZip();  <-- there is problem in this place!
```

!Uncaught (in promise)

Maybe somebody knows what the problem is...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used the same name for the static resource file (JSZip) that the library itself wants to use (JSZip). Consider `import JSZIP from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/jszip'` instead, then use `loadScript(this, JSZIP)`.

You could also choose to just make this into an ES6 module. Create a new LWC component named jszip. In that component, copy dist/jszip.min.js from the manual download option into lwc/jszip/jszip.js, and remove the `html` file. Now, add two lines at the end of this script:

```
const JSZip = window.JSZip;
export default JSZip;
```

This should allow you to import without using `lightning/platformResourceLoader` at all.

```
import JSZip from 'c/jszip';
```

This is a trick I've previously used to [import the YouTube embedded player](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/310787/2984).

Comment: Yes, you are wright.

One more question:  I have integration with Google Drive (by Named Cred) =>  i show GD files on my LWC.
So, I want to have ability to download folder with files in zip.  BUT: I haven`t blobs of these files. these files have only GD properties (name, id, links,parents,...)

Do you have some ideas?

Comment: @НазарЦихуляк To get the blobs, you use [files.get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/files/get). It's unclear at first glance if there's a batch mode one can leverage, but you'd start there; download each file, then you can use JSZip to compress the files to a single file.

Comment: but it doesn`t work
async downloadFolder(event){
        const folder = event.detail;
        let zip = new JSZip();
        const content = await getFolderContent({folderId: folder.id});
        const files = content.files;
        for(const file of files){
            const upFile = await getFile({folderId:file.id});
            zip.file(upFile.name, upFile);
        }
        zip.generateAsync({type: 'blob'})
        .then((content)=>{
            saveAs(content,folder.name +'.zip')
        })
        .catch(() => {
            console.log('er);
        });
    }

Comment: When I tried to do this particular trick, it was giving me error that process.nextTick is not supported. Any way to bypass this ?

Comment: @Nazar process.nextTick is a Node feature, and not available in browsers. Make sure you're grabbing a browser-compatible version, or you can try using browserify to convert your existing code into a bundle that should be browser compatible.